# Create a list of datafames using for loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have approximately 200 data frames with different names, and I want to create a list including all these data frames as elements. I' ve created a character vector including all those names and I tried for loop, but it didn't work. Any ideas ?

example (which doesn't work):

```
wr1 <- data.frame(name = c("Maria","Nikos"), age = c("18","25"))
new <- data.frame(name = c("George","Marianna"), age = c("45","34"))
vage <- data.frame(name = c("Argyris","Nikos"), age = c("37", "26"))

the_names <- c("wr1","new", "vage")


new_list <- list()

for(i in length(the_names)){
  something <- the_names[i]
  new_list <- list(new_list,something)
}
```

The list is created, but it has only 2 elements (not 3) with the character names of the data frames and not the data frames.

I know that I am doing something wrong, but I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach` instead. For this case I use `get` to extract the variable from environment. And as `foreach` result in a list by default so you have a list of data.frame.

```r
wr1 <- data.frame(name = c("Maria","Nikos"), age = c("18","25"))
new <- data.frame(name = c("George","Marianna"), age = c("45","34"))
vage <- data.frame(name = c("Argyris","Nikos"), age = c("37", "26"))

library(foreach)

the_names <- c("wr1", "new", "vage")

list_df <- foreach (name = the_names) %do% {
  get(name)
}

# Assign names of data to the list
names(list_df) <- the_names
list_df
#> $wr1
#>    name age
#> 1 Maria  18
#> 2 Nikos  25
#> 
#> $new
#>       name age
#> 1   George  45
#> 2 Marianna  34
#> 
#> $vage
#>      name age
#> 1 Argyris  37
#> 2   Nikos  26
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Works perfectly!!! Thank you for the really fast answer, as well as for introducing me the "foreach" package!!!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder a little about the motivation to use a for loop, why not just `list`ing this together?

```
wr1 <- data.frame(name = c("Maria","Nikos"), age = c("18","25"))
new <- data.frame(name = c("George","Marianna"), age = c("45","34"))
vage <- data.frame(name = c("Argyris","Nikos"), age = c("37", "26"))

new_list <- list(wr1, new, vage)
```

**Edit:** If its really necessary to take it from a character vector, the following should also work:

```
new_list <- lapply(the_names, function(L) eval(parse(text = L)))
```

or simply:

```
new_list <- mget(the_names)
```

Comment: Because I have approximately 200 data frames with different names as I mentioned in my message.

Comment: But what's the difference to create a character vector instead of list arguments? O.k., you may read this from a file? Then see my edit.